# SSIS 2012 Unable to deploy Package with project level connections

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

SSIS 2012 Developer Edition:-

I made a project with project level connections and all the packages in it are using these connections. 
When I try to deploy the same project on the SQL server integration catalog, it is giving an error

> Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the operation_messages view for the operation identifier ‘41120’. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error : 27203).

I tried publishing the same project after changing the project level connections into package level connections and it worked.

Is there any way by which I can deploy a project with project level connections without changing each connections into package level?

Find attached the images showing the error.

Looking forward for your recommendations as it has been roadblock in my project.

Comment: You can absolutely deploy a project with project-level connections, this will be fixable. Did you try doing what the error message suggested?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages AS OM WHERE OM.operation_id = 41120` Run that on the server you are deploying to. Copy the messages and edit your question with the results

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the issue always be caused by a timeout for big projects, this is a known issue.
Solution:
 1. Right click: Build Solution
 2. Copy the ispac file and paste it on the Server you want to do the deployment
 3. Create a bat file with the below code

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe" /Silent /ModelType:Project /SourcePath:"D:\FolderX\X.ispac" /DestinationServer:"." /DestinationPath:"/SSISDB/Test/Test"
```

4. Execute it